# slapd Address Book working but only search

Tags: openldap, thunderbird

I'm setting up an Address Book using LDAP (slapd) in Debian. Right now I have succesfully installed and it's working (using phpldapadmin as frontend).

The only problem I've seend it's in the client side (using Thunderbird), I can access the contacts that there are in the server, if a search them I can find them, if I change the information in the server and go to see it at the client I can see that the information is update. But when I go to see the list of contacts I can't see any.

I tried at debugging it, using

```
# slapd -d 1
```

And I see the search queries, but I don't see any query for listing the contacts of the address book. What could be wrong?

Comment: [This is my problem](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/locutus/how-to-list-exchange-ldap-groups-and-users-in-thunderbird-30434). The solution proposed there doesn't work for me because it's for ActiveDirectory and I'm using slapd/openldap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, Thunderbird never requests the full address book from an LDAP server. You can do a search for `@` and it will show all entries with an email address (but that's not very convenient).

The easiest way I found so far is to install the [Contacts Sidebar](http://extensions.sanjer.nl/) add-on for Thunderbird 5. When you choose the LDAP server, the full list of contacts appears automatically.

Don't worry too much about the search filter, unless you have a mix of objects in LDAP (eg you're using it for things other than contacts); leaving it at the default `(objectclass=*)` worked fine for me.

Comment: OK. Contacts Sidebar is working. Thank you! So, it is how it's supposed to work Thunderbird? :S